# find replace variable integer wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace, find, unique-id

I'm having a really hard time finding a solution for this.

I'm trying to do a find/replace in a WordPress database where the strings i'm searching for contain unique number IDs.

Here's what i'm trying to find:

```
<div id="unique-entry-id-147" class="blog-entry">
```

Where `unique-entry-id-147` is a different number on every post.

Fore example:

```
...
<div id="unique-entry-id-147" class="blog-entry">
<div id="unique-entry-id-135" class="blog-entry">
<div id="unique-entry-id-68" class="blog-entry">
<div id="unique-entry-id-23" class="blog-entry">
...
```

the command i'm working with (in my limited knowledge of SQL) is

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '<div id="unique-entry-id-147" class="blog-entry">','');
```

NOTES:

1) The code with the unique ID is contained WITHIN the blog post content as misc code from an import of a previous database.I was able to clean up everything else but this..

2) i'm not actually trying to *replace* it with anything, I just want to remove it (hence, the empty "replace" field). If there's a better way, i'm open.

***Thank you!***

Comment: another way would be to export the .sql file and look for <div id="unique-entry-id-147" class="blog-entry"> and replace with nothing '' and re-import it back into the database.

Comment: @unixmiah - I'm trying to avoid doing a find-replace on every single one since they are all unique.

`<div id="unique-entry-id-147" class="blog-entry">, <div id="unique-entry-id-136" class="blog-entry">, <div id="unique-entry-id-38" class="blog-entry">`

...hundreds of unique IDs...